# Android: Resources.getDimensionPixelSize() increments negative px values by 1?

Tags: android, pixel, dimension

I have a entry in my `dimens.xml` like so:

```
<dimen name="alert_dialog_height">-2px</dimen> //wrap_content is -2
```

but when I call

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.alert_dialog_height);
```

it returns `-1`?

Other notes: when `alert_dialog_height = -3px` it returns `-2`. Can anyone explain? Thanks!!

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? It's true that `WRAP_CONTENT` is `-2`, but it's just `-2`; no `px`, no `dp`, no `sp`. It's a flag, rather than an dimensional measure. Other than that, the off-by-one discrepancy is probably due to the rounding that `getDimensionPixelSize()` does.

Comment: Hi Mike, I need to define wrap_content in dimen file and specifying -2px is a way to do it as stated by another stackoverflow post.

If it rounds, how does -2 round to -1?

Comment: One reason I can think of is since the getDimensionPixelSize ensures it is at least 1 pixel value. It thinks all numbers < 0 is zero, so it always tries to increment it by 1. Dunno if this is true, need someone to confirm.

Comment: I didn't trace through all the source, but it ends up adding `0.5f` to a `float`, then casting to `int`, which is probably ultimately why. Here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#669, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/util/TypedValue.java#303

Answer (score 0):

Use like This way

```
 <integer name="custom_wrap_content">-2</integer>

 <dimen name="alert_dialog_height">@integer/custom_wrap_content</dimen>
```

Comment: Hey this doesn't compile, but I know what you are trying to tell me. I already have a solution to my wrap_content in dimens file problem. Im just curious as to why getDimensionPixelSize is giving me a weird value that's all.

Comment: disable inspect checking in xml